# How to hide a URL and token in email?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I hide the URL in my password reset email?

In my backend, this is how I have the URL setup:

accountService.js

```
async function sendPasswordResetEmail(account) {
  let message;
  const resetUrl = `https://www.example.com/accounts/reset-password?token=${account.resetToken.token}`;
  message = `<p>Please click the below link to reset your password, the link will be valid for 1 day:</p>
                   <p><a href="${resetUrl}">${resetUrl}</a></p>`;

  await sendEmail({
    to: account.email,
    subject: "Reset Password",
    html: `<h4>Reset Password Email</h4>
               ${message}`,
  });
}
```

When the email arrives to my inbox, the URL looks like this in the email:

```
https://www.example.com/accounts/reset-password?token=7a77f2273c599d2d49d1293bfb3b8a2a370528c6561189d6e229612eb51f1e0c219a3d92a20c8eda
```

I'd like to just show the user a link that says `click here`

How do I do this?

Comment: change your a tag to -> <a href="${resetUrl}">click here</a>

Comment: There's nothing e-mail specific here, you can format it just like any other HTML link. If you don't know any HTML, find a quick beginner's guide.

Comment: Are you using NodeMailer? It has an HTML option... is that what's now working?

Comment: "*How do I do this?*" If you want more readable output, why have you elected to interpolate `resetUrl` between your `<a></a>` instead of the text `click here`, per your spec...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't interpolate the URL into the text of the `<a>`?

```
<a href="${resetUrl}">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Basic HTML is worth an answer?